# Will self be retained by ARC in this situation?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, automatic-ref-counting

I have the following code inside a method:

```
UIImageView* imageBlk = self.image;
self.finishBlock = ^{
    imageBlk.hidden = YES;
}
```

Under ARC, will self get retained by the block because image is a property of self? Who owns imageBlk? Self?

Comment: checkout the block chapter in http://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2011-09-30-automatic-reference-counting.html , maybe the blog post clarify your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Will `self` be retained by the block?** No it will not. The `imageBlk` variable is not an instance variable so the block has no need to retain `self`. There is no worry of a retain cycle in your posted code.

**Who owns `imageBlk`?** `imageBlk` is a stack variable. The block will retain the variable. ARC takes care of this retention and well as properly releasing it when appropriate.

**Who owns `self`?** We can't answer that from this code. Who ever has allocated the object will own it. Who ever has retained it also owns it.

Comment: Makes sense, but leads to another question, which I'll ask in another thread. Why does the block retain self if imageblk would have been an instance variable (does it do it for both private ivars and properties?) Retaining the object itself should be enough to assure its existence? So why retain self?

Comment: See "Avoiding Strong Reference Cycles When Capturing self" at https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithBlocks/WorkingwithBlocks.html

Answer (score 0):

No, as `imageBlk` is not the same as `self.image`! `imageBlk` is a local variable and not owned by anyone. `imageBlk` inside the block is a readonly-copy of `imageBlk` and not the same variable. If you want it to be the same variable, you have to use the `__block` declaration.

Comment: If imaBlk is not owned by anyone who's responsible to release it at the end of the scope? I thought that by default, variables get retained, not copied inside a block. The pointer is a copy, just like in any other C function, but the object to which it points should be the actual object. If you were true, only instances that implemented NSCopying could have been passed inside a block. So the question remains.

Comment: @Meda if you are using ARC, it is responsible of calling release at the end of the scope, else you would be, but not self. A variable declared outside of a block without the `__block` spezifier is readonly inside of the block. You cant assign a new value to `imageBlk` inside of the block. An object is not the same as a variable. The Object inside and outside is the same, but the variable is not.

Answer (score 0):

Code is fine. 
Variable declared outside of block is readonly and you cant change its value.
But...you dont change the value! You just "call a method" on the value, which is [imgBlock setHideen:YES];
Perfectly legal. All will work flawlessly. Block will retain the imgView as long as needed.

Comment: What you say is true but you don't answer the question - will `self` be retained by the block?